# Linkedin API search finder adCreatives

Tags: python, linkedin-api

I'm currently working with the LinkedIn marketing API in python and I'm migrating to the version 2.0.0.

I was trying to get the `adCreatives` via `adCampaigns` urn in this way:

```
import requests

url = 'https://api.linkedin.com/v2/adCreativesV2?q=search&search=(campaigns:(values:List(urn%3li%3sponsoredCampaign%XXXXXXX, other_urns)))&fields=campaign,id,reference,status,changeAuditStamps,type'

response = request.request(url=url, headers={"X-Restli-Protocol-Version": "2.0.0",
                           "Authorization": f"Bearer {access_token}"}, method="GET")
```

but I bumped into this error:

```
response.json()
>>> {'message': 'Request would return too many entities.', 'status': 400}
```

The first thing that I've tried was to reduce the amount of `adCampaigns` urn from the `List(...)` but because of I was still getting this error I've remove also all the parameters, but turns out it was pointless.

The strange fact is that when I do the same API call with the following url

```
url = 'https://api.linkedin.com/v2/adCampaignGroupsV2?q=search&search=(accounts:(values:List(urn%3li%3sponsoredAccount%XXXXX)))&fields=account,id,name,status,changeAuditStamps,runSchedule
```

I get the correct response with the `status: 200`. This also happen with `adAccounts` and `adCampaigns`.

Does anybody know how to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Solution

---

I found out that the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/marketing/integrations/ads/account-structure/create-and-manage-creatives?tabs=http#search-for-creatives) states that the search field is `campaign`; moreover I fix the urn replacing `%3` with `%3A` (althought that was not the problem as you can see from the `adCampaignGroups` API call) and now the correct url is:

```
url = 'https://api.linkedin.com/v2/adCreativesV2?q=search&search=(campaign:(values:List(urn%3Ali%3AsponsoredCampaign%3AXXXXX)))&fields=campaign,id,reference,status,changeAuditStamps,type,variables'
```

It is still unclear how the working search field parameter for `adCampaigns` and `adCampaignGroups` is `accounts` although [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/marketing/integrations/ads/account-structure/create-and-manage-campaign-groups?tabs=http#search-for-campaign-groups) states that is `account`.

Comment: Working with the API can be tricky. When using the X-RestLi-Protocol-Version: 2.0.0 header, you need to use the above syntax with search=(campaign:(values:List(xxx))) but when that header is not included, the syntax should be search.campaign.values[0]=xxx. I can confirm that when searching accounts, the search param is "account" not accounts. It looks like they've corrected the docs w.r.t. that